# Android Studio not showing preview for XML layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create a side navigation bar and i am designing the side navigation drawer but the layout is not showing in preview.
According to stack-overflows answers i tried to solve by changing app theme and cache data but none worked for me, is there anything xml attribute i am missing here? or i have to initialize it in java class? (i haven't initialized navigation bar in my java class). i am newbie in android so please help me.
Here is the preview of my problem.
[image]

Comment: Hello, have you any render error? (like https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEub0.png) 
Most of case when I had this error was because a library missing or have error in importation
Maybe you can check if you correctly import androidx library and not the "normal" android library

Comment: @Benjamin hello. thank you for your reply. I have imported '' implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' '' this library, and this library is working fine in default navigation project (provided by android studio). in my case i dont knoe what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the side navigation drawer that comes as a default activity, You can use this to familiarise yourself with the code, hence making it simpler to make your own custom side-nav drawer.

If you need more help customising your drawer check out this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-navigation-drawer-in-an-android-app--cms-30263), it might help you out a bit. For java.

This one for [kotlin](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/android-navigation-drawer-example-kotlin/).